# Proper way to cut text variable into 4 different variables

Tags: bash, networking, network-programming

I have a variable with the below text in it. I am struggling to figure out how to split it into 4 different variables.

[Text stored in $t_config]

```
session writelock

random command

random command

random command

session writeunlock

session writelock

random command

random command

session writeunlock

session writelock

random command

random command

session writeunlock

session writelock

random command

random command

session writeunlock
```

I am able to split the first one but not sure how to do the other three. I did it this way:
`x1=$(echo "$t_config"| sed '/session writeunlock/q')`

Will this be easier with a IFS read line?

Any help or tips would be appreciated

EDIT 1)
`$t_config` is loaded from a file.

Each block of writelock-writeunlock would be a different variable.EX) b1,b2,b3,b4

Comment: how do you populate `t_config` ? what is your expected output?

Comment: $t_config is loaded from a file.

Each block of writelock-writeunlock would be a different variable.EX) b1,b2,b3,b4

Comment: first, if you are reading from a file probably it is better to read it line by line avoiding store its content in a variable.
second, what do you expect to do wih each variable? maybe you don't need them at all? what is your overall requirement?

Comment: The file im reading is a large text file containing configs for networking equipment. But the file has 4 separate configs which are blocked off by the writelocks

Comment: Read the file line by line and compare the line against "session writelock" and "session writeunlock".

Comment: Do you care about blank space and newlines?  Would you care if you got rid of all of the blank lines?

Comment: Joao- I will give that a try when I get back into the office
Jasonmclose: I already removed newlines in the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is for each block of lines between /session writelock/ and /session writeunlock/ to be assigned to a variable b1, b2, etc.

This is one way to do it. As commenters have already suggested, reading line-by-line is probably more efficient. However, I've assumed you need to use the variable.

```
#!/bin/sh

t_config=`cat moo`

echo "$t_config" | {
        INDEX=0
        NL="
"
        while read LINE; do
                case $LINE in
                        ("session writelock")
                                OUTPUT=""
                                ;;
                        ("session writeunlock")
                                let INDEX=$INDEX+1
                                VAR="b$INDEX"
                                eval "$VAR='$OUTPUT'"
                                OUTPUT=""
                                ;;
                        (*) OUTPUT="$OUTPUT$NL$LINE";;
                esac
        done

        # now do something with the variables
        echo "b1:$b1"
        echo "b2:$b2"
        echo "b3:$b3"
        echo "b3:$b4"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of opening up my mind a little.. Im new to bash and scripting. This helped a lot!